# Select the IDs using group by condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset where I need to find the diseased patients in consecutive rows.

I'll share my sample dataset with a clear explanation.

```
ID Normal Des1 Des2 Des3 Des4
12 0      1    0    0    0
12 1      0    1    0    0
12 1      0    1    0    0
12 1      0    1    0    0
14 0      1    0    1    0
18 1      0    0    0    0
18 1      0    0    0    0
18 1      0    0    0    0
11 0      1    0    0    0
11 0      1    0    0    0
11 0      1    0    0    0
22 1      0    0    0    0
```

Here I specified the Diseased list of the dataset. I required the IDs for those who are in the same Disease in all the period.
Assume that I need an output for Patients who never fall in any Diseased criteria(IDs 18, 22) I stored it as a new set(Undiseased), Later I need to get the same model for Des1 patients (IDs 11). I tried the below code to fetch the data. but It returns partial output.

```
select ID from tablename where 
(normal = '1' and Des1 = '0' and Des2 = '0' and Des3 = '0' and Des4 = '0')
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query using [COUNT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 function.

```
Create table MySampleTable (Id int, Des1 int, Des2 int, Des3 int)
insert into MySampleTable Values
(12, 0, 1, 0),
(12, 1, 0, 1),
(12, 1, 0, 1),
(18, 1, 0, 0),
(18, 1, 0, 0),
(11, 0, 1, 0),
(11, 0, 1, 0)

; with cte as (Select Id
     , Count(distinct Des1) as TotDes1
     , Count(distinct Des2) as TotDes2
     , Count(distinct Des3) as TotDes3
from MySampleTable
group by Id
)
Select Id from cte where TotDes1 = 1
and TotDes2 = 1 and TotDes3 = 1
```

It looks like as shown below with the output.

[image]
Here is the live [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d4bc185dba9a39a676e304191623c11).

You can also use the having clause as shown in the query below.

```
Select Id
     /*
     , Count(distinct Des1) as TotDes1
     , Count(distinct Des2) as TotDes2
     , Count(distinct Des3) as TotDes3
     */
from MySampleTable
group by Id
having Count(distinct Des1) = 1 and Count(distinct Des2) = 1 
and Count(distinct Des3) = 1
```

Comment: You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258616/9071943) with a more simple approach.

Comment: Thank u all 4 ur support. I think I shared a basic Example but It doesn't work with my data I'll share my code here. Kindly suggest some Ideas 2 resolve it. `select patient_id from tablename where 
(normal = '1' & highrisk = '0' & Ulcerated = '0' & Cellulitic = '0' & Necrotic = '0' & Amputation = '0')
group by patient_id` This code returns the specified condition for IDs & hides the other lines which not met the condition like `normal = '0' & highrisk = '1' & Ulcerated = '0' & Cellulitic = '0' & Necrotic = '0' & Amputation = '0'` How could I get the all the group by ID are in the same model

Comment: @SathishJay You should either edit the current question and add the new sample data, expected output and the logic of output. It will be better if you will ask another question and provide the reference link of this question. Unable to understand the logic now as you gave in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d860c631598d1a2c38184f4b0489fd7f)

You can achieve it in this simple way

```
;WITH cte_TempTable AS(
 Select DISTINCT Id, Des1, Des2, Des3
 from MySampleTable
)
SELECT Id
FROM cte_TempTable
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(Id) = 1
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: 12 is not in the expected output please read the OP post again.

Comment: @Suraj Kumar Did you check my answer with the newest like demo?

Comment: Yes I have checked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Sathish Jay

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `apply` :

```
select t.id
from table t cross apply
     ( values (Des1, 'Des1'), (Des2, 'Des2'), (Des3, 'Des3'), (Des4, 'Des4') 
     ) tt(DiseasFlag, DiseasName)
where DiseasFlag = 1
group by t.id
having count(distinct DiseasName) = 1;
```